# Can't confirm Jacob interface in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jacob

I have a project to work  with COM and I use JACOB interface but I don't know confirm Jacob library into NetBeans! somebody know, can help me?
Thanks for your helps!

Answer (score 0):

Create a /lib directory, add your 3rd party JARs, and tell NetBeans that you want to add all the JARs in that directory to your project CLASSPATH.

Comment: I don't understand.Can you be more specific instructions, such as images? Thanks so much!

Comment: No images.  How do you write Java or use NetBeans without knowing how CLASSPATH works?